# Como comparar valores, dentro de um único vetor? EM C

Tags: c, array, comparação

Fiz meu código do seguinte modo, como colocado abaixo. Porém, se eu coloco 2 número repetidos ele diz que tem somente 1 numero repetido, se eu coloco 4 números repetidos, ele diz que tem 6 números repetidos.Já não sei como fazer isso, queria somente comparar valores dentro de um único vetor.

```
main(){
int numeros[5],contador,numerosIguais,contador2;
numerosIguais=0;
for(contador=0; contador<5; contador++){
    printf("Digite aqui o numero n%c %i\n",248,contador+1);
    scanf("%i",&numeros[contador]);
}
    
for(contador=0; contador<5; contador++)
{
    for(contador2=contador+1; contador2<5; contador2++){
    
    if(numeros[contador]==numeros[contador2]){
        numerosIguais=numerosIguais+1;
    }
}
}
printf("A quantidade de numeros iguais e %i\n",numerosIguais);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual o resultado esperado se sua entrada for: 1, 2, 3, 2, 1? No caso de seu programa ele efetivamente só considera 1 quando existe uma única repetição (só incremente 1 vez a variável numerosIguais) agora se existem várias repetições ele incrementará indevidamente por causa do primeiro loop e todos os a frente que ele considera no segundo loop, tenham ou não sido já  considerados. Faça um teste de mesa mas repense sua lógica.

Comment: Não tem como eu fazer um teste de mesa, com uma coisa que eu não aprendi. Que é comparar vetores.